# Facebook redirect after login not working when url is dynamic

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

This is my code:

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'scope'         => 'publish_actions',
    'redirect_uri'  => 'http://mysite.com/',
    ));
```

It works but if I remove redirect_uri it doesn't work anymore.

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'scope'         => 'publish_actions'
    ));
```

According to Facebook domcumentation redirect_uri is optional. 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/

Im trying to redirect the users to the same url they were on before logging in.

**Update: This problem occurs when the url is mysite.com/post23 but when url is mysite.com/staticpage or mysite.com there are no problems**

Any workarounds?

**EDIT: It looks like a bug, it doesn't work with certain url in the same site**

I wil try and report it to Facebook.

Comment: weird, it works for me. which version of php-sdk you are using ?

Comment: I'm using  Facebook PHP SDK (v.3.2.0) from https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this strange problem like this:

Include this line at the top of your files when user is not logged in:

```
$_SESSION['redir_after_auth'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

then check if user is trying to login and that session is set

```
if (isset($_GET['action']) AND $_GET['action']=="fblogin" && isset($_SESSION['redir_after_auth'])) {
    header('Location: ' . $_SESSION['redir_after_auth']);
}

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
        'scope'         => 'publish_actions',
        'redirect_uri'  => 'mysite.com/?action=fblogin'
        ));
```

Answer (score 2):

it should redirect to current url if redirect_uri param not given. check if your getLoginUrl function in base_facebook.php looks like:

```
public function getLoginUrl($params=array()) {
    $this->establishCSRFTokenState();
    $currentUrl = explode("?",$this->getCurrentUrl());
    $currentUrl = $currentUrl[0];

    // if 'scope' is passed as an array, convert to comma separated list
    $scopeParams = isset($params['scope']) ? $params['scope'] : null;
    if ($scopeParams && is_array($scopeParams)) {
      $params['scope'] = implode(',', $scopeParams);
    }

    return $this->getUrl(
      'www',
      'dialog/oauth',
      array_merge(array(
                    'client_id' => $this->getAppId(),
                    'redirect_uri' => $currentUrl, // possibly overwritten
                    'state' => $this->state),
                  $params));
  }
```

Comment: It didn't look exactly like that, I edited the file and then tried again with the same results.